# jQuery's selectors on string not working for Internet Explorer

Tags: internet-explorer, jquery, jquery-selectors

I make an ajax call with jQuery's `$.get()` that returns a string to a function. This string contains both xml and html, and I have to extract some part of the html with jQuery's selectors, for example:

```
$.get(
    url,
    function (xml) {
        $(xml).find('something').whatever();
    }
);
```

In that case, everything works fine with Firefox and Chrome, assuming that the xml var is a string (headers text/html sent in php to be sure). But in IE, it can't find the "something" tag.

Why doesn't this work?

**Update:**

I tried to simplify the problem:

```
var test = "<hello><world /></hello>";
alert($(test).find('world').length);
```

This is working just fine on every browser (displays `1`) but not in Internet Explorer, it displays `0` (only tried on IE7).

How do I fix this problem without having to change the format of the variable in XML?

Answer (score 2):

Since its XML try the following  :

`$(xml).contents().find('something').whatever()`

This something similar to accessing the DOM within an Iframe `<iframe>`

**UPDATE:**

Answer to Floren's comment:

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
  var txt = "<hello><world/></hello>";  
  if (window.DOMParser) {  
   parser=new DOMParser();  
   xmlDoc=parser.parseFromString(txt,"text/xml");  
  }  
  else // Internet Explorer
  {  
    xmlDoc=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");  
    xmlDoc.async="false";  
    xmlDoc.loadXML(txt);  
  }  
  alert($(xmlDoc).find('world').length);  
});
```

For parsing XML string from a local string variable you would have to create a parser object specifically for IE. It may not be required for FF or others.

But for `$.ajax` if the `dataType` is specified as `xml` then this conversion is done automatically and we don't have to create the XML parser.

Comment: Actually, the "xml" variable is a string, not an in XML format, so this isn't working neither.

Comment: Part of the above code was taken from http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_parser.asp

Answer (score 1):

Try to set the dataType to html.

```
$.get(
    url,
    function (xml) {
        $(xml).find('something').whatever();
    },
    'html'
);
```

Comment: Well, this is not working. I believe that the default dataType is html anyway.